# r: Use list of arguments in function

Tags: r, function

I wrote a function to calculate odds ratios of two variables, CI's and bind everything together with the `n` and the name of one of the variables. My example including my function looks like this:

```
library(DescTools)

a <- as.numeric(replicate(1, sample(c(0:1), 100, replace = TRUE)))
b <- as.numeric(replicate(1, sample(c(0:1), 100, replace = TRUE)))
c <- as.numeric(replicate(1, sample(c(0:1), 100, replace = TRUE)))
x <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c))

orr <- function (var1, var2){
  con <- table(var1, var2)
  o <- OddsRatio(con, conf.level = 0.95)
  n <- sum(con[2, 1:2])
  name <- deparse(substitute(var2))
  df <- data.frame(rbind(o), n, "ind.varname" = name)
  return(df)
}

a<-orr(x$b,x$a)
b<-orr(x$c,x$a)
rbind(a,b)
```

Now, in my example, I want to pass a list of arguments to the function (arg2) to have the odds calculated for several variables with the first argument staying the same. Thus, the final output would preferably be a data.frame that looks like the following, just with more lines (see above):

[image]

Does anybody have any tips on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Vectorize(orr, 'var2')(x$a, x)`

Comment: But is there a way to include a command within the function? something like "for i in orr"...

Comment: your function is not vectorized. So NO. there is no way to do that IN the FUNCTION unless you write A NEW function

Comment: Could you, by any chance, give me a hint on how to write that new, vectorized function or could you recommend a good tutorial about that? thanks in advance!

Comment: From which package is `OddsRatio` function from? What output are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, the OddsRatio function comes from the DescTools package. I added that to my example above. I also added the desired output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this function :

```
orr <- function (data, var1, var2){
  val1 <- data[[var1]]
  val2 <- data[[var2]]
  con <- table(val1, val2)
  o <- OddsRatio(con, conf.level = 0.95)
  n <- sum(con[2, 1:2])
  df <- data.frame(rbind(o), n, ind.varname = var2, row.names = NULL)
  return(df)
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(names(x[-1]), orr, data = x, var1 = "a"))

#  odds.ratio    lwr.ci   upr.ci  n ind.varname
#1   1.739130 0.7706866 3.924519 61           b
#2   1.519481 0.6704328 3.443777 61           c
```

Little shorter with `purrr::map_df` :

```
purrr::map_df(names(x[-1]), orr, data = x, var1 = "a")
```